# how to pass props through a Link from react-router-dom?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to pass state using Link

```
<Link to={{ pathname: `/contact/:${contact.id}`, state: { contact }, }}>
```

And this is where I want to get this state passed using link but I'm getting location undefined

```
function ContactDetails({ location }) {
console.log(location);
const { name, email } = location.state.contact;}
```

And this is my Route:

```
<Route path='/contact/:id' element={<ContactDetails />}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just got an answer for this I did this and it resolve my issue

```
<Link to={`/contact/:${contact.id}`} state={{ contact }}>
```